# how to navigate to another view controller from uiview subclass(mapviewcontroller:MKmapview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Im doing an application on mapkit which shows mutiple pins on a map. When the user touches a annotation pin the user will be taken to another detailed view. But the problem is the class which i implemented map is a subclass oF MKMapKit. when i tried to use

```
SupermarketDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[SupermarketDetailsViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

the error is property "navigationcontroller" is not found on object of type mapviewcontroller

how can i navigate from my current view to another view in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

To navigate, you have to embed you mapViewController in an UINavigationControlelr (Storyboard). The crash should be solved then.

Comment: im not using storyboard

Comment: So start your App/this workflow with an UINavigation controller instead of the mapViewController. This means to setup MapViewController as root of the navigation controller. This is possible everywhere. And with or without storyboards.

Answer (score -1):

Your MapViewController doesn't have a navigation controller.

Two ways to show your Details Screen.
1. Embed Navigation Controller to your MapViewController in storyboard.
2. present your DetailsViewController from MapViewController as below

```
DetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController: detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: actually im adding mapviewcontroller as a subview in Mainviewcontroller, i'm not using storyboard for mapviewcontroller

Comment: you can add navigation controller programmatically and push it. If you don't want to have navigation controller. Present your controller with custom animations(like push).